# R write in feather format to byte vector

Tags: r, apache-arrow, feather

**In R, how can a data.frame be written to an in-memory raw byte vector in the feather format?**

The `arrow` package has a `write_feather` function in which the destination can be an `BufferedOutputStream`, but the documentation doesn’t describe how to create such a stream or access its underlying buffer.

Other than that most other packages assume usage of a local file system rather than in-memory storage.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 2):

`BufferOutputStream$create()` is how you create one. You can pass that to `write_feather()`. If you want a `raw` R vector back, you can use `write_to_raw()`, which wraps that. See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/write_to_raw.html for docs; there's a link there to the source if you want to see exactly what it's doing, in case you want to do something slightly differently.